# Connect to Amazon S3 from google apps script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to connect from google apps script to Amazon S3. I want to copy current document into Amazon S3.

I tried below code but getting error while trying to run.
Library used - https://github.com/eschultink/S3-for-Google-Apps-Script
Code is as below

```
function test() {  

 var blob = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBlob();
  var region = 'us-east-2';

    try {
    S3.init("XXXX", "XXX");
    S3.putObject('bucket-name', blob.getName(), blob, region);
   } catch(e) {
    var message = e.toString();
    Logger.log("test - FAIL - unexpected message [" + message + "]");
    Logger.log(e);
  }
```

Error details

> > AWS Error - SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Can someone guide me how to connect to S3 from google apps script.

Thank you.

Comment: The error suggests that there was a problem 'signing' the request using the Access Key and Secret Key. The github code seems to show that it is using a SigV4, which is good. So, either the Access Key and Secret Key combination is incorrect, or the code is not generating the signature correctly. Can you try connecting to a bucket in `us-east-1`, since it is an older region than `us-east-2`, just to check if that works any better?

Comment: thanks for pointing about this region. Internally s3 request was using us-east-1 where as my bucket was in us-east-2

Comment: Now am able to upload file to S3 but getting "Failed to load PDF document." while opening file from S3. Looks like file got corrupted during upload to S3


  `var blob = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs('application/pdf');
  var s3 = new S3('XXXXX', 'XXXX');
  s3.putObject("bucket", blob.getName(), blob, {logRequests:true});`

Comment: Feel free to create a new question with the details.

Comment: okay sure thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are either missing or did not post the configuration function. According to the documentation you are following you should have something that looks like this:

> Testing
>
> Run the tests of the library from a separate App Script instance as >follows (replacing the environment properties with your own AWS access >key / secret):
>
> ```
> function runTests() {
> S3.setTestEnv({
>   "awsAccessKeyId":"{{replace this with your access key}}",
>   "awsSecretKey":"{{replace this with your secret}}",
> });
> S3.runTests();
> //if running in Spreadsheet context, you can uncomment this
> //Browser.msgBox("All tests passed");
> }
> ```
>
> Check View –> Logs to verify everything went OK, or see where in the >tests it died.  If someone wants to point me to a JSUnit-equivalent for >Google Apps Script, that’d be awesome. (or better yet, get Jasmine/Karma >working for this).

You can use the S3.runTests(); function to see if it is configured correctly.

See https://engetc.com/projects/amazon-s3-api-binding-for-google-apps-script/

Comment: Now am able to upload file to S3 but getting "Failed to load PDF document." while opening file from S3